# TextWatcher Class or interface?

Tags: android

In book and Internet, for example here [Android Handling many EditText fields in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115800/android-handling-many-edittext-fields-in-a-listview), TextWatcher is class, but on android devoloper it is interface http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html.
And Eclipse say, that it is interface.
Who is right?)

Comment: I copied his code and Eclipse say it si wrong - The type TextWatcher cannot be the superclass of MyTextWatcher; a superclass must be a class

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the answer, not the question. Anyways, I'd say that the answer was largely general because you do not extend an interface, you implement it. I'd reckon that they meant `class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher`

Answer (score 1):

TextWatcher is an interface. In the example you've given, it's used as an interface, and the MyTextWatcher class **implements** the TextWatcher interface. If TextWatcher were a class, it would need to use **extends**.

Interface:

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
```

Class:

```
private class ThisWontWork extends TextWatcher {
```

Answer (score 0):

TextWatcher is interface...in android.text.TextWatcher

```
public interface TextWatcher implements NoCopySpan
```